# htaccess ReWrite rule removes slash adds www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

NOTE: additional spaces are to mask that these are "links" in my question. (I am a noob)

I have a site that I want to insure that all traffic to `www.playground.com` (plus any following like `index.html` or `stuff.php`, etc.) is redirected/rewritten to `https://playground.com` (plus any following if applicable)

I have an htaccess with rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.playground\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://playground.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This works as expected if I type www. example.com then I redirect to "`https://playground.com`"

But anytime I add an item to the end of the URL then the redirect is wrong.

I type in `www.playground.com/index.html` then redirect is:      `https://www.playground.comindex.html` and errors

I type in playground.com/ index.html then redirect is: same as above and errors

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The missing slash is not being caused by those rules, something else is causing that

Comment: Could this be caused by the way I set up the .conf file for sites-available then?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.